# What is the difference between “secp…” and “sect…”?

Tags: elliptic-curves, reference-request, nist

The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) recommended elliptic curve domain parameters to have names such as **“secp…”** and **“sect…”**.

For example: *“**secp**224k1”* and *“**sect**571k1”*.

What is the difference between **“secp…”** and **“sect…”**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sect curves are curves over a binary field. From [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/sylvain.duquesne/master/standards/sec2_final.pdf) (chapter 3):

> The example elliptic curve domain parameters over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ have been given nicknames to enable them to
>   be easily identified. The nicknames were chosen as follows. Each name begins with sec to denote
>   ‘Standards for Efficient Cryptography’, followed by a $t$ to denote parameters over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ , followed by a
>   number denoting the field size $m$, followed by a $k$ to denote parameters associated with a Koblitz curve
>   or an $r$ to denote verifiably random parameters, followed by a sequence number.

While the secp curves are over fields over a prime field - or $\mathbb{F}_p$ in mathematical representation. Please read elliptic curve tutorials to understand the difference between the calculations for prime and binary fields.

Comment: Note that the field size for curves is usually taken to be equal to the *effective* key size (and it is actually the size of the secret value, but the public key is larger). Keys can be *encoded* in different ways, and their binary notation will often not directly reflect the key size.